# Is there a way to get a function to perform the same operation on a list of variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

E.g. I'd like to perform a command like `blitzer(blitzer(:,4)<0.5,5)` on a list of variables (or all the variables in the workspace) in MATLAB.

So I'd like to perform it on comet, dasher, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `who` function:

```
s = who;
for i = 1:length(s)
    temp = eval(s{i});
    answer{i} = temp(temp(:,4)<0.5,5);
end
```

Comment: Or if you want to update the original values instead of saving the results to a new variable, replace the second line in the for loop with: `assignin('base',s{i},temp(temp(:,4)<0.5,5))`